# Using P3.6.3 on P2.7:-- Syntax Error on print ('config: '), config

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the `SyntaxError` when I run a Python 2.7 code with Python 3.6.3:--

```
print ('config: '), config
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The ^ sign is pointing at "t" of print.

How can I fix this?

Comment: While this line is bizarre, it's not technically a syntax error on either Python 2 or Python 3. You probably have an issue on the previous line.

Comment: Also, Python 2 code isn't compatible with Python 3 code anyway.

Comment: The Python 2 code is from a simulation program. No issue reported.

Comment: I am asking how to convert Python 2 code into Python 3 code?

Comment: user2357112 is right that the above code runs, the problem may be on a preceding line.

Comment: `set(list(range(nbNodes))` has 3 opening parentheses and 2 closing parentheses.

Comment: Preceding line is empty line.

Comment: The one before that, then. You had a deleted comment with a missing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks , it is ok now  after I add in extra closing parenthesis on "set(list(range(nbNodes)) has 3 opening parentheses and 2 closing parentheses. – user2357112 39 secs ago"

Comment: Thus I presumed the python 2 code should be ok in Python 3, since no more Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

for python3 use:

> `print ('config: ',config)`

Comment: it is ok now after add in missing closing parenthesis in preceding line.

Comment: Dont just include code. Kindly explain how does it solves op problem

Comment: Preceding above codes, it is found that "set(list(range(nbNodes)) has 3 opening parentheses and 2 closing parentheses." discovered by user 2357112. So after adding one closing parenthesis, it is solved.

Comment: nodesSinceTheBeginning = set(list(range(nbNodes)))

    # for the manual tests
    # TTL = 5

    print ('config: '), config